# How to increase/change a value in a dataset with a condition in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

What I want to do is: create a for loop that iterates through the data, if the probability ends in an even number I want to add 0.1 to it, if the color is red I want to increase the cost of that item by 10%.

Something is wrong with my syntax. I can't figure how to correctly do what I want. I keep getting this error: `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`. Also, can I use %2 if the value is a float?

Please help.
Thank you

Here's my code:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['Probability'] %2 == 0:
        df['Probability'] += 0.1
    if df['Color'] == 'Red':
        df['Cost'] += (df['Cost']*.01)
```

Here's the dataset I'm working with:
There are four columns (Color, Probability, Flower, & Cost) and 20 rows

```
     Color  Probability  Flower     Cost
0      Red          2.6       0   378.86
1    Green          1.8       0   329.63
2     Blue          6.1       1   565.46
3    Brown          1.8       1   162.45
4     Blue          5.8       0   490.28
5    Green          6.2       0   516.94
6      Red          4.1       0   441.75
7    Brown          6.5       0   737.20
8     Blue          6.7       1   790.60
9    Green          5.2       0   446.04
10     Red          7.8       1   874.87
11  Yellow          4.1       1   469.51
12   Green          7.0       1   718.52
13     Red          0.5       0   121.99
14  Yellow          9.6       0  1097.16
15   Brown          1.5       0    54.83
16    Blue          6.2       1   610.69
17   Green          8.9       1   825.52
18     Red          2.3       0   346.86
19  Yellow          9.1       1   991.26
```

Comment: don't use for loops and pandas. Pandas can do nearly everything without loops.

Comment: The exercise I'm trying to complete states to use a for loop, so I have to use a for loop. Could you please help me understand what's wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is `df['Probability'] %2 == 0` creates a Boolean series of True/False value, so you can not use `if` with this because its not a single value, but a series of values, and you need to check one value at a time.

Another issue is, you are iterating in the range of `df.shape[0]` which is basically the number of rows, but you are not actually using the value of `i` while assigning the result.

The simplest way to do might be to use `.apply` with a lambda function so that it operates on a single value at a time.

```py
df['Probability'] = df['Probability'].apply(lambda x: x+0.1 if x%2==0 else x)
df['Cost'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Cost']+x['Cost']*.01 if x['Color']=='Red' else x['Cost'], axis=1)
```

```py
     Color  Probability  Flower      Cost
0      Red          2.6       0    37.886
1    Green          1.8       0   329.630
2     Blue          6.1       1   565.460
3    Brown          1.8       1   162.450
4     Blue          5.8       0   490.280
5    Green          6.2       0   516.940
6      Red          4.1       0    44.175
7    Brown          6.5       0   737.200
8     Blue          6.7       1   790.600
9    Green          5.2       0   446.040
10     Red          7.8       1    87.487
11  Yellow          4.1       1   469.510
12   Green          7.0       1   718.520
13     Red          0.5       0    12.199
14  Yellow          9.6       0  1097.160
15   Brown          1.5       0    54.830
16    Blue          6.2       1   610.690
17   Green          8.9       1   825.520
18     Red          2.3       0    34.686
19  Yellow          9.1       1   991.260
```

If you have to loop through the dataframe anyways, you can use `DataFrame.iterrows()` which will give a tuple of values for index, and row at each iteration, and implement the same logic:

```py
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if int(str(row['Probability'])[-1])%2==0: # ending with even
        df.loc[i, 'Probability'] += 0.1
    if row['Color']=='Red':
        df.loc[i, 'Cost'] += row['Cost']*0.01
```

Comment: Could you please apply this in a for loop. The exercise I'm trying to complete ask for it to be done in a for loop.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny  OP is concerned about implementing the logic for the entire column, and not the logic of reminder operator.

Comment: More like the OP is concerned about getting a copy-paste solution for his assignment and doesn't care about the logic.

Comment: @ManishDash I don't think copy/paste solution is always a bad idea, we can learn from such solutions as  well

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, I was wondering if %2 could be used to check if the last digit is even. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: correct. But asking for the addition of a for loop to an existing good answer shows their disinterest in understanding the logic and applying it

Comment: @ManishDash Apparently True, and I can not agree more

Comment: @ThePyGuy, the loop isn't correctly adjusting the entire dataset.

Comment: @TianaChargin that means the logic you are trying to implement is incorrect. Because you want to check whether the probability ends in even number, `%2` doesn't work in that case. You can convert it to a string, and take the last item and check if it is even.

Comment: @TianaChargin, see the updated answer with `int(str(row['Probability'])[-1])%2==0` which converts probability to string type, takes the last item, converts it to integer, then finally checks if it is even or not.

Comment: @ThePyGuy, I had a feeling that I needed to convert to a string and substring the last element and check if that was even or odd. I'm assuming there isn't another way to do it. Also, yes the updated code works. Thank you.

Comment: @ThePyGuy, one of the main issues was that I wasn't iterating through the data correctly, right?

Comment: @ManishDash, I care about the logic. I just have to do it in a for loop and want to understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean auxiallry column and multiply the values with 0.1 and add them, because if the boolean is False it will basically mean `value + 0 * 0.1`

```
df['Probability'] = df['Probability'] + ((df['Probability'] %2 == 0) * 0.1)
```

---

Or you directly use numpy where:

```
import numpy as np
df['Probability'] = np.where((df['Probability'] %2 == 0), df['Probability'] + 0.1, df['Probability'])
```

Comment: Could you please apply this in a for loop. The exercise I'm trying to complete ask for it to be done in a for loop.